# DBSet dynamically register using interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dbcontext, dbset

I want to create a code block which register DBsets dynamically.
I decide to use an empty Interface to catch classes which implement the interface.

Here is my code block.

```
 var entityMethod = typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity");

            foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            {
                var entityTypes = assembly
                    .GetTypes()
                    .Where(t =>
                        t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IBaseEnt))).toList();            

                foreach (var type in entityTypes)
                {
                    entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type)
                      .Invoke(modelBuilder,  null);
                }
            }
```

But my seed methods can't handle my dbsets. Please help me.

I also tried this code block.

```
var entityTypes = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                                  where t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IBaseEnt))
                                           && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
                                  select t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. It is working on EF 6.1.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var entityMethod = typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity");
            foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            {
                var entityTypes = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                                  where t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IBaseEnt))
                                           && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
                                  select t;

                foreach (var type in entityTypes)
                {
                    entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type)
                      .Invoke(modelBuilder, null);
                }
            }
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```